# How to get last 5 or 6 records based on given recordset

Tags: mysql

I am stuck in generating a query. I need a something that will get the last 6 records if the last row in the given record set's event value is 2, and get the last 5 records id the event is 1. The given records are samples of what the data looks like in my MySql table.

Table Structure

```
 CREATE TABLE `timelog` (
  `timeLogId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `event` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`timeLogId`)
  )
```

Here's my current attempt in solving the said problem:

```
SELECT timeLogId, event FROM (SELECT * FROM timelog ORDER BY timeLogId DESC LIMIT 6) as T ORDER BY timeLogId ASC
```

Recordset 1

```
timeLogId | event
1         | 1
2         | 2
3         | 1
4         | 2
5         | 1
6         | 2
7         | 1
8         | 2
```

result:

```
timeLogId | event
3         | 1
4         | 2
5         | 1
6         | 2
7         | 1
8         | 2
```

Recordset 2

```
timeLogId | event
1         | 1
2         | 2
3         | 1
4         | 2
5         | 1
6         | 2
7         | 1
```

result:

```
timeLogId | event
3         | 1
4         | 2
5         | 1
6         | 2
7         | 1
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I've provided the create statement for the table structure.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT T2.*
FROM
(
SELECT T1.TIMELOGID, T1.EVENT
FROM    TIMELOG T1
WHERE T1.TIMELOGID = (SELECT MAX(TIMELOGID) FROM TIMELOG)
) S
JOIN TIMELOG T2 ON 
    CASE 
    WHEN S.EVENT = 1 THEN T2.TIMELOGID >= S.TIMELOGID - 4
    WHEN S.EVENT = 2 THEN T2.TIMELOGID >= S.TIMELOGID - 5
    END
;
```

Comment: How were you able to come up with this solution?

Comment: ? Can you expand on your comment

Comment: Well, the solution does work and is greatly appreciated, but could provide an explanation?

Comment: The execution order is 1) sub query 2) join 3) select

Comment: I've posted an updated question regarding this problem. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40103389/how-to-get-last-5-or-6-records-based-on-given-recordset-per-user