# How to get last 5 or 6 records based on given recordset per user

Tags: mysql

This is an update to my question [How to get last 5 or 6 records based on given recordset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40101315/how-to-get-last-5-or-6-records-based-on-given-recordset/40102173#40102173).

I need a something that will get the last 6 records if the last row in the given record set's event value is 2, and get the last 5 records id the event is 1. The given records are samples of what the data looks like in my MySql table.

Table Structure

```
 CREATE TABLE `timelog` (
  `timeLogId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `event` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`timeLogId`)
  )
```

Here's my current attempt in solving the said problem:

```
SELECT timeLogId, event FROM (SELECT * FROM timelog ORDER BY timeLogId DESC LIMIT 6) as T ORDER BY timeLogId ASC
```

Recordset 1

```
timeLogId | user    |  event
1         | bigfish |      1
2         | catThum |      1
3         | dogBark |      1
4         | bigfish |      2
5         | catThum |      2
6         | dogBark |      2
7         | bigfish |      1
8         | catThum |      1
9         | dogBark |      1
10        | bigfish |      2
11        | catThum |      2
12        | dogBark |      2
13        | bigfish |      1
14        | catThum |      1
15        | dogBark |      1
16        | bigfish |      2
17        | catThum |      2
18        | bigfish |      1
```

result:

```
 timeLogId | user    |  event
 7         | bigfish |      1
 10        | bigfish |      2
 13        | bigfish |      1
 16        | bigfish |      2
 18        | bigfish |      1
```

Recordset 2

```
timeLogId | user    |  event
1         | bigfish |      1
2         | catThum |      1
3         | dogBark |      1
4         | bigfish |      2
5         | catThum |      2
6         | dogBark |      2
7         | bigfish |      1
8         | catThum |      1
9         | dogBark |      1
10        | bigfish |      2
11        | catThum |      2
12        | dogBark |      2
13        | bigfish |      1
14        | catThum |      1
15        | dogBark |      1
16        | bigfish |      2
17        | catThum |      2
18        | bigfish |      1
19        | catThum |      1
20        | dogBark |      1
21        | bigfish |      2
```

result:

```
timeLogId | user    |  event
7         | bigfish |      1
10        | bigfish |      2
13        | bigfish |      1
16        | bigfish |      2
18        | bigfish |      1
21        | bigfish |      2
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly more complicated. The T sub query allocates a row number to each user which is then joined to the s sub query with the where statement deciding which rows should be returned

```
SELECT T.timelogid,t.user,t.event
FROM
(
SELECT T1.TIMELOGID, t1.user,T1.EVENT
FROM    TIMELOG T1
WHERE T1.TIMELOGID = (SELECT MAX(TIMELOGID) FROM TIMELOG)
) S
JOIN 
(
select t2.*,if(user<>@p , @rn:=1,@rn:=@rn+1) rn,@p:=user p 
from (select @rn:=0,@p:='') rn,TIMELOG T2 
order by user ,timelogid desc
) t
on t.user = s.user 
where t.rn <=
    CASE 
    WHEN S.EVENT = 1 THEN  5
    WHEN S.EVENT = 2 THEN  6
    END
order by t.timelogid
;
```